# creating xml file with namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create a xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order xmlns="urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-basdaorg:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01order-v3.xsd">
```

I have the following code:

```
    Dim xsi As XNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Dim schemaLocation As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-basdaorg:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01order-v3.xsd"
    Dim order As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01"

    Dim root As New XElement("Root", New XAttribute("Order", order.NamespaceName), _
                             New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName), _
                             New XAttribute(xsi.NamespaceName + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation.NamespaceName), _
                             New XElement("Child", _
                                          New XElement("DifferentChild", "other content")), _
                             New XElement("Child2", "c2 content"), _
                             New XElement("Child3", "c3 content"))
```

however when i run the code i get the following error:

```
xmlexception was unhanded
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

Edit

ok so i got the namespaces to work with the following code:

```
Dim xsi As XNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        Dim schemaLocation As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-basdaorg:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01order-v3.xsd"
        Dim order As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01"

        Dim root As New XElement(order + "Order", _
                                 New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
                                 New XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation),
                                 New XElement("OrderHead", _
                                              New XElement("Schema", New XElement("Version", "3.05")),
                                              New XElement("Parameters", New XElement("Language", "en-GB"), New XElement("DecimalSeparator", "."), New XElement("Precision", "20.3")), _
                                              New XElement("OrderType", "Purchase Order", New XAttribute("Code", "PUO"))), _
```

but now in my xml i have:

```
<OrderHead xmlns="">
    <Schema>
      <Version>3.05</Version>
    </Schema>
    <Parameters>
```

is there any way of getting rid of the blank xmlns="" within the orderHead tag?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you get from this:

```
Dim order As XNamespace = "urn:schemas-basda-org:2000:purchaseOrder:xdr:3.01"

Dim root As New XElement(
    order + "Order", 
    New XElement(order + "Child", _
                 New XElement(order + "DifferentChild", "other content")), _
    New XElement(order + "Child2", "c2 content"), _
    New XElement(order + "Child3", "c3 content"))
```

Sorry, but I don't have time to test it right now.

Comment: Look closely at my example and then look at yours.

Comment: ahhh perfect i spotted it! its the order + that i was missing on every element! thanks for your time